# How to determine marginal density function

Tags: statistics, density-function

I am a beginner in statistics, and am self-studying. I have trouble understanding the marginal density function. I was wondering if any of you could please kindly help me with this problem.

[image]

How can I determine the marginal density functions fx and fy? And also the marginal means mx and my.

Answer (score 1):

Start with making a picture in $\mathbb R^2$ drawing the lines $x=-1,x=1,y=-1,y=1-2x$, i.e. the borders of the area on which $f$ takes value $\frac14$. Note that equality $y=1-2x$ can also be written as $x=\frac12-\frac12y$.

---

In general for a fixed $x\in\mathbb R$: $$f_X(x)=\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty}f_{X,Y}(x,y)dy\tag1$$and for a fixed $y\in\mathbb R$:$$f_Y(y)=\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty}f_{X,Y}(x,y)dx\tag2$$

If $x\notin[-1,1]$ then $(1)$ gives $0$ and if $x\in[-1,1]$ then:$$f_X(x)=\int_{-1}^{1-2x}\frac14dy$$
(Have a look at your picture to get some insight concerning the borders).

If $y\notin[-1,3]$ then $(2)$ gives $0$ and if $y\in[-1,3]$ then:$$f_Y(y)=\int_{-1}^{\frac12-\frac12y}\frac14dx$$
(Have a look at your picture to get some insight concerning the borders).

Work this out.

Further we have:$$\mathbb EX=\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty}xf_X(x)dx=\int_{-1}^{1}xf_X(x)dx$$and: $$\mathbb EY=\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty}yf_Y(y)dy=\int_{-1}^{3}yf_Y(y)dy$$

Work this out.

Comment: if we have that $-1\leq y \leq -2x+1$ , wouldn't it be $\frac12-\frac12y\geq x$? why in your integral the $ \frac12-\frac12y$ is the lower bound?

Comment: @RamiroScorolli $y\leq-2x+1\iff x\geq\frac12-\frac12y$.

Comment: you are dividing by $-2$ but not changing the sign of the inequality.

Comment: @RamiroScorolli Repaired. Thank you again.

Comment: now it perfect, your welcome!

Comment: Thank you. One more question, is it possible to determine fxy if only fx and fy were known?

Comment: Not in general. Exception on this: if $X $ and $Y $ are independent then $f_{X,Y} $ is the product of $f_X $ and $f_Y $.

Comment: I see. Thanks. Just one more question, how can I draw the joint density function fxy in 2D? It seems simple but I am confused.

Comment: Actually the function should be drawn in 3D. Value  $\frac14$ on the area I mention in my answer and value  $0$ elsewhere.